# How to send HTTP requests with ESP8266 AT COMMAND?

Tags: firebase, command-line, serial-port, esp8266, cloudant

I want to send HTTP requests to Firebase or Cloudant using AT commands. I'm able to connect to my router and ping to Google:

```
AT+PING="www.google.com"

+34

OK
```

For example, in Firebase:

```
AT+CIPMODE?

+CIPMODE:0

OK

AT+CIPMUX?

+CIPMUX:1

OK
AT+CIPSTART=1,"TCP","https://myapp.firebaseio.com/my_doc.json?mykey",80

ERROR
```

Or, for Cloudant:

```
AT+CIPSTART=3,"TCP","https://USERNAME-password@username-bluemix.cloudant.com/estado/doc_estados",8080

ERROR
```

Is there a way to see what error occurs?

I've seen several examples using Arduino, but I don't want use Arduino.

Comment: `https://myapp.firebaseio.com/my_doc.json?mykey` is not a valid hostname.

Comment: I will not make my credentials available, this hostname worked via curl.

Comment: That's not a hostname, but an URL. AT commands on ESP8266 don't have built-in support for HTTP, so you can't directly use the URL. You need to implement the [HTTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Example_session) on top of the TCP connection yourself or use some library that does it for you.

Comment: How I can transmit/receive content inside LAN? And, exists any method to use a ESP8266 for web connection?